# linq and string array

Tags: c#, linq

```
var result=list.select(element=>element.split['_']).list();
/* I want to extract the part of the file name from a list of file names */
```

I have an array of file names , and i want to extract part of name from the array for each file name

example:

> 0-policy001_Printedlabel.pdf
>   1-policy002_Printedlabel.pdf
>   2-policy003_Printedlabel.pdf
>   3-policy004_Printedlabel.pdf

Now I want to use Linq to extract an array out of the above array , which gives me only

> policy001,policy002,policy003,policy004

Can you please help me? I am new to lambda expression.

Comment: @DanielMann I think the first section is what he has tried but obviously that's not clear enough due to formatting.

Comment: Is the `0-`, `1-` and so on, part of the filename, or just an index?

Comment: @HansKesting this is what confused me when I put my answer

Answer (score 4):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@".+(policy[0-9]+).+");

var newarray = yourarray.Select(d=>regex.Match(d))
                        .Where (mc => mc.Success)
                        .Select(mc => mc.Groups[1].Value)
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> output = fileList.Select(fileName => fileName.Split(new char[] {'-','_'})[1]).ToList()
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, was going to change my answer after I understood what was being asked for haha.

Answer (score 1):

**If the numbers are indexes**

```
string[] output = fileList.Select(fileName => fileName.Split(new char[] {'_'})[0]).ToArray();
```

**If the numbers are part of the file name**

```
string[] output = fileList.Select(fileName => fileName.Split(new char[] {'-', '_'})[1]).ToArray();
```

Comment: That will return the number at the start too

Comment: @JustinHarvey I see the formatting of the question made me think that the numbers represented the indexes...

Answer (score 0):

If it's always so strict:

```
string[] result = list
    .Select(fn => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn)
                      .Split(new[] { '-', '_' }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                      .ElementAtOrDefault(1))
    .ToArray();
```